# Creation of Panel Data set in R

Tags: r

Programmers, 
I have some difficulties in structuring my panel data set.
My panel data set, for the moment, has the following structure:

Exemplary here only with T = 2 and N = 3. (My real data set, however, is of size T = 6 and N = 20 000 000 )

Panel data structure 1:

```
Year | ID | Variable_1 | ... | Variable_k |
1    |  1 |     A      | ... | B          |
1    |  2 |     C      | ... | D          |
1    |  3 |     E      | ... | F          |
2    |  1 |     G      | ... | H          |
2    |  2 |     I      | ... | J          |
2    |  3 |     K      | ... | L          |
```

The desired structure is:

Panel data structure 2:

```
Year | ID | Variable_1 | ... | Variable_k |
1    |  1 |     A      | ... | B          |  
2    |  1 |     G      | ... | H          |
1    |  2 |     C      | ... | D          |
2    |  2 |     I      | ... | J          |  
1    |  3 |     E      | ... | F          | 
2    |  3 |     K      | ... | L          |
```

This data structure represents the classic panel data structure, where the yearly observations over the whole period are structured for all individuals block by block.

My question: Is there any simple and efficient R-solution that changes the data structure from Table 1 to Table 2 for very large data sets (data.frame).

Thank you very much for all responses in advance!!

Enrico

Comment: In your desired output (panel 2), shouldn't the second line be `2 | 1 | G | ... | H`?

Comment: No, the entire row should be reordered. That's exactly what you proposed! Thanks!

Comment: But for Year=2 and ID=1, in panel1 you have G..H, whereas in panel2 you have E..F. Surely they should be the same..Reordering the rows doesn't change the data..

Comment: You're right, I didn't see my mistake. That's the correct desired output:

Comment: Year=2 and ID=1 with G  H as well as Year=2 and ID=2 with I J.

Comment: Tables are now corrected! Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reorder the rows of your dataframe using `order()`:

```
df=df[order(df$ID,df$Year),]
```